# How to save dash app for local machine use as executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, executable, plotly-dash

I've built a dash app that works for the intended purpose, I can drop specific format of excel files and then they are restructured and key information is plotted etc.
But I've got it running on the development server.
I would like to be able to save it as an executable or similar so other users can easily use it without needing to use python or see any code.
Is this possible?
And would the user need python installed on their machine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I created a [basic working example](https://github.com/DouwMarx/dash_by_exe) where the [Dash hello world](https://dash.plotly.com/layout) is packaged as a .exe using [Pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/). The Dashboard is served locally using [Waitress](https://pypi.org/project/waitress/) and is also set up to be able to load data and show images.

Some limitations of this approach include slowish opening times and rather large file sizes (~150Mb when using for instance dash, pandas, numpy, waitress etc.). In some cases, this is acceptable considering the convenience of creating executables of Dash apps simply using Python know-how.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible to create an executable from a dash app, but you could try heroku, it won't build an executable but other users will be able to connect to the webapp without the need to install python.

There are plenty of [tutorials](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-your-first-web-app-using-python-plotly-dash-and-google-sheets-api-7a2fe3f5d256) showing how to do it.

Comment: Thank you, does using heroku mean it will be hosted externally? I'd want each user to be able to use the app without internet access and completely independently of other users.

Comment: Sorry but no, heraku needs an internet connection as it will create a web page for the app.