# how can I make a .net with a .py?

Tags: python, .net

This is the first time I try to do this. I have a 7 thousand lines script of python 3.9 dash plotly, and with vs2019 I need to make it for windows microsoft store (I supose it will have to be in .Net).

How can I do this ... please let some days to not bring me down the q. This is important for me because I'm not going to learn a C now or make this 7 thousand lines of code for C.

I have not tried much, becase I don't know how to use vs ... so please be helpfull for me to learn how to do this.

I expect to receive as a result learn how to make a .py to .Net.

Comment: Convert it into exe (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62953312/how-to-save-dash-app-for-local-machine-use-as-executable) (https://community.plotly.com/t/convert-dash-to-executable-file-exe/14222)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I thought I had to make a .Net ... but I need to make one of this for the windows store: .msix, .msixbundle, .msixupload, .appx, .appxbundle, .appxupload, .xap

Comment: I made the .exe with this:   https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe